# R introduce new rows for all the permutations of two columns and group them

Tags: r, scripting, group-by, permutation

I have a table with week numbers and day numbers, which I would like to group to create all the possible combinations and make a new table with them.

[image]

I tried:

```
 w =(book2$week_no)
 d = (book2$day_no)

 b=expand.grid(w,d)
 b=b[c(TRUE,FALSE),]
```

It gives me all the permutations.

```
    Var1 Var2
  1  week1 day1
  3  week2 day1
  5  week1 day2
  7  week2 day2
  9  week1 day1
  11 week2 day1
  13 week1 day2
  15 week2 day2
```

But I have no idea on how to create the new table using those results. I am sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you described your required output perfectly clearly. You said you want to "group to create all the possible combinations", but grouping generally means aggregating into a smaller table. From your screenshot, it looks like you want to duplicate rows from the input table to produce a larger table. More specifically, it looks like you want to take a cartesian product between the row sets of each unique `week_no` value, with the additional wrinkle that you want the pairs of product rows to be stacked sequentially in the output table, rather than joined side-by-side. Here's a good way to do that:

```
df <- data.frame(raw_id=1:4,week_no=c('week1','week1','week2','week2'),day_no=c('day1','day2','day1','day2'),val=c(234,123,235,111),stringsAsFactors=F);
df[t(do.call(expand.grid,split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no))),];
##     raw_id week_no day_no val
## 1        1   week1   day1 234
## 3        3   week2   day1 235
## 2        2   week1   day2 123
## 3.1      3   week2   day1 235
## 1.1      1   week1   day1 234
## 4        4   week2   day2 111
## 2.1      2   week1   day2 123
## 4.1      4   week2   day2 111
```

Let's break that down:

---

```
seq_len(nrow(df));
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

The above produces the vector of row indexes that exist in the input table.

---

```
split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no);
## $week1
## [1] 1 2
##
## $week2
## [1] 3 4
##
```

Then we split the vector on the `df$week_no` values to produce a named list, where each component holds the row indexes of one of the unique values of `week_no` from the input table, with that value captured nicely as the component name (although we won't use the name in the solution).

---

```
do.call(expand.grid,split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no));
##   week1 week2
## 1     1     3
## 2     2     3
## 3     1     4
## 4     2     4
```

The format of the split list is perfect for passing directly as the arg list of `do.call()` in order to call `expand.grid()`. This is how we get the cartesian product of row indexes between the two `week_no` values.

We can get your required output by indexing out the above pairs of rows from the input table, stacking them sequentially by following the index table left-to-right along rows, then top-to-bottom along columns (often just called "by row"). But there are two reasons why we can't use the above object as the row dimension subscript directly: (1) it's a data.frame, and we need a simple vector of row indexes, and (2) even if we could pass it as a matrix to the row subscript, matrix data is naturally laid out "by column" in memory, meaning the indexes would be followed in the wrong order with respect to your required output.

---

```
t(do.call(expand.grid,split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no)));
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## week1    1    2    1    2
## week2    3    3    4    4
```

We can solve both of the aforementioned problems with a single call to `t()`, which automatically coerces the data.frame to a matrix and transposes it, so the natural "by column" traversal will result in the correct indexing order.

---

```
df[t(do.call(expand.grid,split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no))),];
##     raw_id week_no day_no val
## 1        1   week1   day1 234
## 3        3   week2   day1 235
## 2        2   week1   day2 123
## 3.1      3   week2   day1 235
## 1.1      1   week1   day1 234
## 4        4   week2   day2 111
## 2.1      2   week1   day2 123
## 4.1      4   week2   day2 111
```

Voila.

---

Ah, almost forgot about the `group` column in the required output. Since the output table is produced in a regular way, meaning it's produced from a cartesian product of input rows, we can derive the group values after-the-fact. Here's how to do it, assuming you've stored the above result as `res`:

```
res$group <- rep(seq_len(prod(table(df$week_no))),each=length(unique(df$week_no)));
res;
##     raw_id week_no day_no val group
## 1        1   week1   day1 234     1
## 3        3   week2   day1 235     1
## 2        2   week1   day2 123     2
## 3.1      3   week2   day1 235     2
## 1.1      1   week1   day1 234     3
## 4        4   week2   day2 111     3
## 2.1      2   week1   day2 123     4
## 4.1      4   week2   day2 111     4
```

---

I just realized that neither your question nor my answer address the case of three or more unique values in `week_no`. My solution happens to take a variadic cartesian product between all `week_no` row sets, but I realized that you might have preferred taking only binary cartesian products between all pairs of `week_no` row sets, which requires a different solution. It was a challenging and interesting problem to work on, but I believe I got it:

```
df <- data.frame(raw_id=1:6,week_no=c('week1','week1','week2','week2','week3','week3'),day_no=c('day1','day2','day1','day2','day3','day3'),val=c(234,123,235,111,300,400),stringsAsFactors=F);
df;
##   raw_id week_no day_no val
## 1      1   week1   day1 234
## 2      2   week1   day2 123
## 3      3   week2   day1 235
## 4      4   week2   day2 111
## 5      5   week3   day3 300
## 6      6   week3   day3 400
res <- df[t(do.call(rbind,apply(combn(seq_along(unique(df$week_no)),2L),2L,function(is,rs) expand.grid(rs[[is[1L]]],rs[[is[2L]]]),split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no)))),];
res$group <- rep(seq_len(nrow(res)%/%2L),each=2L);
res;
##     raw_id week_no day_no val group
## 1        1   week1   day1 234     1
## 3        3   week2   day1 235     1
## 2        2   week1   day2 123     2
## 3.1      3   week2   day1 235     2
## 1.1      1   week1   day1 234     3
## 4        4   week2   day2 111     3
## 2.1      2   week1   day2 123     4
## 4.1      4   week2   day2 111     4
## 1.2      1   week1   day1 234     5
## 5        5   week3   day3 300     5
## 2.2      2   week1   day2 123     6
## 5.1      5   week3   day3 300     6
## 1.3      1   week1   day1 234     7
## 6        6   week3   day3 400     7
## 2.3      2   week1   day2 123     8
## 6.1      6   week3   day3 400     8
## 3.2      3   week2   day1 235     9
## 5.2      5   week3   day3 300     9
## 4.2      4   week2   day2 111    10
## 5.3      5   week3   day3 300    10
## 3.3      3   week2   day1 235    11
## 6.2      6   week3   day3 400    11
## 4.3      4   week2   day2 111    12
## 6.3      6   week3   day3 400    12
```

We can compare the above result with what we would get under my first solution:

```
res <- df[t(do.call(expand.grid,split(seq_len(nrow(df)),df$week_no))),];
res$group <- rep(seq_len(prod(table(df$week_no))),each=length(unique(df$week_no)));
res;
##     raw_id week_no day_no val group
## 1        1   week1   day1 234     1
## 3        3   week2   day1 235     1
## 5        5   week3   day3 300     1
## 2        2   week1   day2 123     2
## 3.1      3   week2   day1 235     2
## 5.1      5   week3   day3 300     2
## 1.1      1   week1   day1 234     3
## 4        4   week2   day2 111     3
## 5.2      5   week3   day3 300     3
## 2.1      2   week1   day2 123     4
## 4.1      4   week2   day2 111     4
## 5.3      5   week3   day3 300     4
## 1.2      1   week1   day1 234     5
## 3.2      3   week2   day1 235     5
## 6        6   week3   day3 400     5
## 2.2      2   week1   day2 123     6
## 3.3      3   week2   day1 235     6
## 6.1      6   week3   day3 400     6
## 1.3      1   week1   day1 234     7
## 4.2      4   week2   day2 111     7
## 6.2      6   week3   day3 400     7
## 2.3      2   week1   day2 123     8
## 4.3      4   week2   day2 111     8
## 6.3      6   week3   day3 400     8
```

Comment: thanks so much bgoldst, you helped me to fix the problem and learn many things :)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. You did not create all permutations by two groups

If you look closely, your permutations are repeated (first four lines are identical to the last four lines)

`expand.grid` will give you all combinations of the two vectors without anything on the "grouping".

A corrected version of your code would be:

#### Edited:

```
b<-rbind(expand.grid(week = unique(w),day = unique(d)),expand.grid(day = d,week = w))
```

## 2.Add the new columns

```
b$group<-rep(1:4,each = 2)
w<-sapply(1:nrow(b),FUN = function(z){
        which(book2$week_no==b$week[z] & book2$day_no==b$day[z])
       }
    )
b$pre_raw_id<-w
b$val<-book2$val[w]
```

Comment: hi DeveauP, thanks for the quick reply. the corrected version gives 32 records but every 2nd record is a duplicate, and when i do  b=b[c(TRUE,FALSE),] it repeats each 4 rows. can you help me to get it right please?  but the adding new rows part was really helpful

Comment: I edited my answer so that it fits your data. I had done it on my computer with : `b<-rbind(expand.grid(week = 1:2,day = 1:2),expand.grid(day= 1:2,week = 1:2))`

Comment: hey im sry Deaveau, the edited rbind command gives me 20 records when i applied for my data. But I learnt   many thinks from you, thank you so much for your kind help :)